# Confusion as to initialization (or lack thereof) of object

Tags: java, object, initialization

```
package lab9;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Date;

public class AccountManager
{
    // the account
    private Account account;
    // reader for reading user input
    private Scanner reader;
    private Transaction transaction;
    private AccountManager accountmanager;



    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class AccountManager
     */
    public AccountManager(Account account, Transaction transaction, AccountManager accountmanager)
    {
        this.account = account;
        reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.transaction =transaction;
        this.accountmanager=accountmanager;




    }

    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE ACCOUNT MANAGER APPLICATION");
        boolean finished = false;

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            // get amount
            System.out.print("Transaction amount to add?\n>");
            String inputAmount = reader.nextLine();
            double amount = Double.parseDouble(inputAmount);

            // get type
            System.out.print("Transaction type?\n>");
            String type = reader.nextLine();

            // TO DO: get reference
            System.out.print ("Transaction reference?\n>");





            // date is today's date
            Date date = new Date();

            // TO DO: create transaction and add to account


            System.out.println("Transaction added");
            account.displayTransactions();

            // TO DO: display balance
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Transaction t=new Transaction();

        Customer cust = new Customer("Fernando", "Alonso");
        Account account = new Account(cust, "12345");
        AccountManager accountmanager= new AccountManager (account,t, accountmanager);



        // TO DO: create AccountManager object and call start method

    }

}
```

Enclosed is my code. I am trying to create an AccountManager object and call its
start method.

However, I am getting an error identifying that the Accountmanager object may not have been intialized.

I am confused by this greatly; I thought

```
this.accountmanager=accountmanager;
```

1. Was the initialization of the accountmanager object? My (limited) understanding is that the initialization involves =.

such as

```
a=10;
```

And if that were true, then that to me suggests that this.accountmanager=accountmanager would be valid? (Which I am assuming is incorrect, but just wanted to provide my thinking process).

2. I had previously gotten an error returned to me, identifying that a non-static variable transaction cannot be referenced from a static context.

To remedy this I included:

```
 Transaction t=new Transaction();
```

So that in fell in the scope of the static method. Is that legal/correct?

Error message:

```
 AccountManager accountmanager= new AccountManager (account, t, accountmanager);
```

"variable accountmanager might not have been initialized"

Comment: I've answered the question, but I *strongly* recommend that you edit it to include the *exact* error message, including where it's reported.

Comment: @Jon Skeet; 

Can I please clarify with you:

Transaction t=new Transaction();
So that in fell in the scope of the static method. Is that legal/correct?

Comment: That's in the scope of the `main` method, yes. But that doesn't look like it's got anything to do with your problem, which is caused by your use of `accountmanager`. You should ask *one question per post*. The `t` variable part is irrelevant to the rest of your question, and you should remove it.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was contributing to the error.

Comment: Well the error message doesn't mention `t`, and the error you'd previously received has gone, right? Have you read my answer yet? It fully explains the problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
AccountManager accountmanager= new AccountManager (account, t, accountmanager);
```

You're declaring a variable, and trying to *read* from that variable in the same statement that gives it an initial value.

Here's a simpler example, to show how it's nonsensical:

```
int y = 10;
int x = y + x;
```

What would you expect the value of `x` to be at the end of that? You've said its *initial* value should be the value of `y` plus its current value... but it doesn't *have* a current value, because you're trying to find its initial value!

I strongly suspect that you shouldn't have that their constructor parameter at all though. Why does one `AccountManager` need a reference to another? You should:

- Remove the `accountmanager` field
- Remove the `accountmanager` constructor parameter
- Change the local variable declaration and initialization to:

  ```
  AccountManager accountManager= new AccountManager(account, t);
  ```

  (Note the capital M in `accountManager`, to follow Java naming conventions. I'd probably rename `t` to `transaction` for clarity too.)

Comment: Error has gone, has been replaced with a new error:

constructor AccountManager in class lab9.AccountManager cannot be applied to given types;

  required: lab9.Account,java.util.Scanner,lab9.Transaction
  found: lab9.Account,lab9.Transaction
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @IronUhlan: Well that's not the code that you posted, as the code you've posted doesn't have a `Scanner` constructor parameter. But either way, it's a different problem that you should investigate and try to solve yourself, asking a new question if *absolutely* necessary. Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugging service.